# Email Template Issue

Tags: magento-1.9, email-templates

Upon testing default email templates built into magento, I am getting an error in the email that is received.  I have not modified any of the templates yet as I wanted to run a test to make sure the default templates worked first.  The email has an error at the top and the bottom and it also appears the css isn't styling the template.

Located at the top of the email:

```
{Error in template processing} {{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}
```

Located at the bottom of the email:

```
{Error in template processing}
```

I am grasping at straws trying to figure out what is going on here.  Is the `email-inline.css` file supposed to be in a folder somewhere?  Is that what is missing?  I cannot seem to find the file within the skin folder.  I just cannot seem to find the root of this issue.  I am new to magento and need a little assistance.  I am using 1.9.0.1 Magento FYI.

Please help

Comment: I have searched and searched but have not found any solution to this?  Surely there is something simple to fix this problem.  Has anyone ever run up against this??  Please help

Comment: Check the error logs for any more clues. Disable any third party minification modules, refresh the cache and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Both `email-inline.css` and `email-non-inline.css` must be placed in your theme skin folder.

Copy this files from:
`skin/frontend/base/default/css`
to
`skin/frontend/default/YOUR-THEME/css`

Be sure that you've already created Header and Footer e-mail template files.